# Loading JSON data to a Jekyll site and the same-origin policy

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, same-origin-policy

I’d like to add an App.net feed to a Jekyll site, pulling the JSON feed on the client using JavaScript from `/users/@nick/posts`. But then I learned about the same-origin policy. The JSON feed obviously comes from a different domain and since I don’t have control over the website server nor the App.net’s API, it looks like I can’t use CORS nor JSONP. What are my options?

(An interesting catch is that the code appears to work so far, using `XMLHttpRequest` in Chrome and `jekyll serve`. Is there an exception for local URLs? Or did I get the same-origin policy wrong?)

Comment: Well, that was quick. Anyway, if someone else is interested, [App.net supports JSONP](https://developers.app.net/reference/make-request/responses/#jsonp), so there’s an easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

Unique workaround stands as a local script proxyfying the distant json.
Bear in mind that the same-origin browser policy is here to enforce security.
You will break that jail with a workaround.